# Can't access media library

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having an issue with Drupal's Media module.
When adding/editing a content, I can't access the media library. A popup appears saying "error getting media". It seems there is an error 500 on /media/browser/list but can't see why. I checked the permissions of the module. Also, default/files is 777.

I've tried this solution (hack) but it still does not work :
http://drupal.org/node/747998

It does work in local though. So it must be an issue with the server.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why. It was a memory limit issue.

I increased the php memory limit and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but was getting 500 (Internal Server Errors) when browsing the Media Library.

I was getting dozens of these message in my browser's console log:

```
 GET /sites/default/files/styles/square_thumbnail/public/filename.jpg?itok=LyjUyjae 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The Drupal Status Report at `/admin/reports/status` showed that the **files directory was not writable**.

> "The directory sites/default/files is not writable. You may need to set the correct directory at the file system settings page or change the current directory's permissions so that it is writable."

I changed the directory permissions on `/sites/default/files` and the problem was fixed.